# Find if a member is descendant in parent-child relationship table

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I just came up an exercise I can't solve. In a table like the one above:

```
Father|child
a     |b
b     |c
c     |d
d     |e
```

is it possible to write a single query that tells if 'e' is a descendant of 'a'  or/and if 'a' is an anchestor of 'e' in sql or relational algebra?

My guess is no because I'll have to join to the first query that could check father/child relation a new subquery for every "parental" level I want to investigate.

Comment: yes, it is possible. you can do it with recursive queries.

Comment: Note: the correct term in English is "*Parent-Child*", not "*Father-Child*".

Comment: Look for recursive queries as @vkp said(there was also a recursive operator in some versions of relational algebra). For postgresql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: You need to explain or reference exactly what you mean by "relational algebra" because there are many versions with different operators hence different abilities, and even different notions of "relation". Also, your question is a faq, google your title with 'stackoverflow' & your tags.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
CREATE TABLE FamilyRelation (
    parent int, 
    child int,
    primary key(parent,child)
);
```

you can do (in postgresql ; this is standard SQL-99, but ... :)

```
WITH Recursive Descendants(Parent,Child) AS 
(
    SELECT Parent, Child
    FROM FamilyRelation
  UNION ALL
    SELECT P.Parent, C.Child
    FROM FamilyRelation C JOIN Descendants P ON (P.Child=C.Parent)
)
SELECT * from Descendants
Order by Parent, child
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0e4d/6